# Custom file input button won't select files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a simple file selection button using css/javascript. The issue I am having now, is that it the custom button is being considered null when I click on it to activate the the hidden file input button. How can I activate the hidden file input button using a simple_form input and normal html button?

```js
//story.js
$(document).ready(function () {
 let realFileBtn = document.getElementById("story_story_video");
 let customBtn = document.getElementById("story-file-upload-btn");
 let customText = document.getElementById("story-file-upload-text");

 if(customBtn){
  customBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
   realFileBtn.click();
  });
 }


 realFileBtn.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (realFileBtn.value) {
   customText.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value;
  } else {
   customText.innerHTML = "No video selected"
  }
 });
});
```

```css
//story.scss

//Real File Upload Button
#story_story_video {
  display: none;
}

// Custom File Input Button
#story-file-upload-btn {
  background-color: #bf318d;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  border: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#story-file-upload-btn:hover {
  background: #942a69;
  cursor: pointer;
}

// Custom Text that shows which file you chose
.story-file-upload-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<!--_form.html.erb-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <button type="button" id="story-file-upload-btn">Select Video</button>
  <br>
 <%= f.input :story_video, class: 'form-control', label: false %>
 <span id="story-file-upload-text">No video selected</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript Stacktrace

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (story_file_upload_btn.self-eb557f85ebb94b2e2cbd43807a4fc248af863cd160e98e593784d35dfff6daf2.js?body=1:13)
    at mightThrow (jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js?body=1:3584)
    at process (jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js?body=1:3652)
```

Answer (score 0):

For file inputs, you need to use [file_field](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files):

```
<%= f.file_field :story_video, class: 'form-control', label: false %>
```

Also as a side note, if you're using `form_with` instead of `form_for`, you'll need to specify input id explicitly, because `form_with` does not generate ids.

Comment: I'm using simple_form. I will check to see if that's the problem.

Comment: There's seems to be an issue with the customBtn event listener. Since, I am loading this button inside of the modal. There could be problems with how it is picking up responses from the button.

Comment: Error tells you that element does not exist when page is loaded. Does modal exist in the DOM, or is it attached dynamically? Because if latter, then you'll have to attach event listener only after modal is shown.

Comment: Its attached dynamically through AJAX/Rails Partials. That could definitely be the issue, since no other solution is working that I tested so far.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to use jasny since its a proven to work solution, and its incredibly versatile.

Updated code

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new"  data-provides="fileinput">
          <span class="btn story-file-upload-btn btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select Video</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change Video</span><input type="file" name="..."></span>
          <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
          <%= f.input :story_video, as: :file, class: 'form-control', input_html: {hidden: true, accept: ('video/mp4')}, label: false %>
          <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none">&times;</a>
        </div>
```